# Instant payment success status for recurring payment's first cycle

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a recurring payment scenario and the checkout flow depends on the payment success status for the first billing cycle. I'm using PayPal's REST API and I have got below questions.

1. Just after a recurring payment agreement is executed, is there any way I can get the payment success status instantly apart from using PDT or IPN?
2. When charging a setup fee apart from the recurring payments, does the IPN/PDT notification for setup fee come before the first billing cycle payment notification?